# Save networkx DiGraph preserving nodes attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to save networkx DiGraph by preserving nodes' attributes.

I have tried with  `nx.write_weighted_edgelist`, `nx.write_edgelist`  and `nx.write_weighted_edgelist` , and after trying (and also looking at https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.html) I know that both adjacency and edge lists does not preserve nodes' attributes.

Now I have seen also the other options in the networkx link, but I don't understand if other commands preserve attributes, and I need to be sure that it works (my code need to create and save more than 5000 graphs and it takes almost a day to run).

So which is the best way to save a graph and preserve nodes' attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you are using an outdated version of the NetworkX docs; you should always use the [stable version](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/).

One format which is guaranteed to preserve node data is the [pickle](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/gpickle.html#format) (although this is deprecated in NetworkX 2.6, it is currently usable):

```py
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_node("A", weight=10)

In [4]: nx.write_gpickle(G, "test.gpickle")

In [5]: H = nx.read_gpickle("test.gpickle")

In [6]: H.nodes(data=True)
Out[6]: NodeDataView({'A': {'weight': 10}})
```

The [GML](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/gml.html) format should also work for most datatypes:

```py
In [8]: nx.write_gml(G, "test.gml")

In [9]: H = nx.read_gml("test.gml")

In [10]: H.nodes(data=True)
Out[10]: NodeDataView({'A': {'weight': 10}})
```

[GEXF](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/gexf.html) works as well:

```py
In [12]: nx.write_gexf(G, "test.gexf")

In [13]: H = nx.read_gexf("test.gexf")

In [14]: H.nodes(data=True)
Out[14]: NodeDataView({'A': {'weight': 10, 'label': 'A'}})
```

So you have several options and can decide based on performance and support for the specific attribute data you are trying to save.

Comment: I just noticed it is the outdated, anyway every solution you gave works fine, thanks!